# How to match against struct fields?

Tags: rust

Let's look into the following code:

```
struct MyStruct {
    field: String,
    key1: String,
    key2: String,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn match_test(&self, x: String) {
        match x {
            self.key1 => {
            },
            self.key2 => {
            },
            _ => {}
        };
    }
}
```

it would yield a compilation error:

```
error: expected one of `!`, `(`, `...`, `..=`, `..`, `::`, `=>`, `if`, `{`, or `|`, found `.`
  --> ./ex_067.rs:10:17
   |
10 |             self.key1 => {
   |                 ^ expected one of 10 possible tokens
```

So this post boils down to the question as to how to match smth among `varname.field` ?

I imagine that is it possible to solve inverting the actual matching thing in such a way:

```
        match self {
            MyStruct { key1, .. } if *key1 == x => {},
            MyStruct { key2, .. } if *key2 == x => {},
            _ => {}
        };
```

Still and all, it imposes to much boilerplate code, on top of inversion.

So, I wonder, if it can be done concise and straightforward ?

How to get rid of inversion (move to `match x {}` from `match self {}`) and `if` stuff, which makes quite a lot of boiler plate code.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, no, since there is `if` stuff boiler plate, on top of inversion, it is not concise definitely. I have provided a nasty solution for it from the start, and it is exactly what is suggested in questions which you point out. But it breaks the logic of program and inflates it.

Comment: @Jim, as you can see, ideologically, I try to match `x`, not `self`, who bothers about `self`? `self` receives `x` and it analyses `x`, so straightforward way would be to `match x { }` not `match self { }`. Not to mention the `if` stuff, which I have used in the topic as well. My question is : how to get rid of inversion and `if` stuff.

Comment: @unegare I see that, but as these questions says, you cannot do it.

Comment: You can change the `match self` to `match x { ... if x == self.keyX ... }`, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be trying to mix the concept of a `switch` (from other languages) vs Rust's `match`, which is pattern matching as opposed to conditionals based on the data (although those conditionals are possible via `match guards`.

Your first example fails because you are trying to `match` on a value, which is how `switch` statements work it nearly every other language. In Rust, the match takes a pattern to bind/destructure your variable to. In this case, you would want to match on any `x`, and then execute the arm which satisfies your `self.keyn == x` guard:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    field: String,
    key1: String,
    key2: String,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn match_test(&self, x: String) {
        match x {
            val if self.key1 == x => {
                println!("{val} is key1");
            },
            val if self.key2 == x => {
                println!("{val} is key2");
            },
            _ => {}
        };
    }
}
```

This may seem like a lot of boilerplate, but `match` statements are super useful with their ability to match inside of enum variants and to destructure other types, and this is just one case where they might not feel the most ergonomic.

Comment: in this case the whole point of using `match` is unfounded, since it would be much simpler just write a chain of `if ... {} else if ... {} else {}`

Comment: I would agree with that. Although, I thought I may be able to help clear up where the initial misunderstanding came from about why it isn't as simple as it seems like it should be.